# What does "lit." mean in boiling point or melting point specification?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, notation

For example, this [Xanthene 99% specification from Sigma Aldrich](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/x201?lang=en&region=US&cm_sp=Insite-_-recent_fixed-_-recent5-2) states:

\begin{array} \\\hline
\text{bp}  & 310-312 ~^\circ\mathrm{C~ (lit.)} \\\hline
\text{mp}  & 101-102 ~^\circ\mathrm{C~ (lit.)} \\\hline
\end{array}

My guess is that it's from literature.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you are correct: “lit.” refers to the literature value.
Usually one would also expect the corresponding reference, but it looks like Merck doesn't attach any to the provided data directly in place.

From *The ACS Style Guide*, section *Reporting Analytical Data* [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/jm068034q), p. 274] (emphasis mine):

> #### Melting and Boiling Points
>
> mp 175.5 °C (lit.<sup>25</sup> mp 175–176 °C)
> mp 225 °C dec
> bp 127 °C
>
> Abbreviations: mp, melting point; bp, boiling point; **lit., literature value**; and dec, decomposition.
> A full space is used between the number and the unit °C; the degree symbol is closed up to the C.
> A superscript number after “lit.” denotes the number of the reference.

*The CSE Style Guide* also recognizes “lit.” as abbreviation for literature in *Appendix 29.2 Common English words used in bibliographic description and their abbreviations* [2, p. 645], further referring to [ISO 832:1994](https://www.iso.org/standard/5195.html).

#### References

1. *The ACS Style Guide: Effective Communication of Scientific Information*, 3rd ed.; Coghill, A. M., Garson, L. R., Eds.; American Chemical Society; Oxford University Press: Washington, DC; Oxford; New York, **2006**. ISBN 978-0-8412-3999-9.
2. *Scientific Style and Format: The CSE Manual for Authors, Editors, and Publishers*, 8th ed.; Council of Science Editors, Ed.; Council of Science Editors; London: in cooperation with The University of Chicago Press: Chicago, **2014**. ISBN 978-0-226-11649-5.